# Octave: Need version 4.0.1 but only 4.0.0 in package archive

Tags: apt, package-management, octave

When I issue

```
sudo apt-get install octave
```

it installs octave 4.0.0. However our instructor tells us this version is broken and we have to install version 4.0.1. So I checked the available versions that the package manager has available:

```
mzh:~ $ sudo apt-cache madison octave
    octave | 4.0.0-3ubuntu9.1 | http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
    octave | 4.0.0-3ubuntu9 | http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

Looks like only 4.0.0 are available. What do I have to do so that I can install 4.0.1?

Comment: you should compile octave from source then

Comment: With Ubuntu, just looking at the version number is not enough, since package maintainers backport fixes. You should check the changelog to see if whatever was broken has been fixed. For example: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/o/octave/octave_4.0.0-3ubuntu9.1/changelog What exactly is "broken", according to your instructor?

Comment: 4.0.2 is available from the [GNU Octave Team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~octave/+archive/ubuntu/stable)

Answer (score 3):

I'm here probably for the same reason...

To get latest version (4.2.1 right now) :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:octave/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install octave
```

Answer (score -1):

You should compile it from source

First make sure this all dependence are installed:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk default-jdk-headless epstool gperf hdf5-helpers javahelper libaec-dev libarpack2-dev libblas-dev libbtf1.2.1 libcsparse3.1.4 libexif-dev libfftw3-dev libflac-dev libfltk-cairo1.3 libfltk-forms1.3 libfltk-images1.3 libfltk1.3-dev libftgl-dev libftgl2 libglpk-dev libgraphicsmagick++1-dev libgraphicsmagick1-dev libhdf5-cpp-11 libhdf5-dev libjack-dev libjasper-dev libklu1.3.3 liblapack-dev libldl2.2.1 libogg-dev libosmesa6-dev libportaudiocpp0 libqhull-dev libqrupdate-dev libqscintilla2-dev libqt4-designer libqt4-dev libqt4-dev-bin libqt4-help libqt4-opengl-dev libqt4-qt3support libqt4-scripttools libqt4-svg libqt4-test libsndfile1-dev libspqr2.0.2 libsuitesparse-dev libvorbis-dev libwmf-dev openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jdk-headless portaudio19-dev qt4-linguist-tools qt4-qmake uuid-dev llvm-3.5-dev
```

The simple method of `sudo apt-get build-dep octave` doesn't seem to work anymore as far as i know

Then :

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-4.0.1.tar.gz
tar xf octave-4.0.1.tar.gz
rm octave-4.0.1.tar.gz
cd octave-4.0.1/
./configure
make -j8
sudo make install
```

By the way, i would suggest you go with the lastest version of `octave`.

Comment: I'm totally lost with definition of package versions to install.

Comment: check out here https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/ ,So far the lastest is 4.2.1

Comment: `make install` is bad idea. `checkinstall` is better.